# cambiar elementos html existentes con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo el siguiente fragmento de código

```
<figcaption data-v-de73d604="">
    <h2 data-v-de73d604="" class="vimeography-title fusion-responsive-typography-calculated" data-fontsize="36"
        data-lineheight="46.08px" style="--fontSize:36; line-height: 1.28;">PurePower rompiendo los limites</h2>
    <p data-v-de73d604="" class="vimeography-subtitle">March 28, 2020</p> <a data-v-de73d604=""
        href="/premium-videos/?vimeography_gallery=2&amp;vimeography_video=401572314" class="vimeography-link"
        title="PurePower rompiendo los limites">View more
    </a>
</figcaption>
```

¿como haría yo para cambiar el **h2** por un **h3** y agregarle un **bold** en Javascript o jquery ?

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora? Cuál es el error que presentas?

Comment: A dónde quieres agregar el bold?

Comment: hola @JheymanMejia hasta ahora ninguno, solo que no tengo muy claro como abordarki,

Comment: @crrlos que tal carlos, agregar el bold en el h2

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código cambia todos los `h2` por `h3`:

```js
//buscar los elementos a reemplazar, en este caso h2
var elementosAnteriores = $("h2");

$.each(elementosAnteriores,function(i,v){
  reemplazarElemento($(v));
});


function reemplazarElemento(elementoAnterior){

//crear nuevo elemento para reemplazar el anterior
var elementoNuevo = $("<h3></h3>");

//extraer los atributos del elemento anterior
var atributosElementoAnterior =  elementoAnterior.prop("attributes");

//copiar los atributos del elemento anterior al nuevo
$.each(atributosElementoAnterior, function() {
    elementoNuevo.attr(this.name, this.value);
});

//copiar el contenido del elemento anterior al elemento nuevo
elementoNuevo.html(elementoAnterior.html());

//reemplazar elemento anterior por el nuevo
elementoAnterior.replaceWith(elementoNuevo);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <h2 data-v-de73d604="" class="vimeography-title fusion-responsive-typography-calculated" data-fontsize="36"
        data-lineheight="46.08px" style="--fontSize:36; line-height: 1.28;">PurePower rompiendo los limites</h2>
        
         <h2 data-v-de73d604="" class="vimeography-title fusion-responsive-typography-calculated" data-fontsize="36"
        data-lineheight="46.08px" style="--fontSize:36; line-height: 1.28;">PurePower rompiendo los limites</h2>
        
         <h2 data-v-de73d604="" class="vimeography-title fusion-responsive-typography-calculated" data-fontsize="36"
        data-lineheight="46.08px" style="--fontSize:36; line-height: 1.28;">PurePower rompiendo los limites</h2>
```

Comment: Que tal amigo mio, gracias por tu pronta respuesta, ciertamente hay más elementos h2, para seleccionar todos los elementos h2 como sería?

Comment: Ya actualicé el código para que actualicé todos los `h2`.  Todos los elementos `h` tienen el estilo bold por defecto.